# Bash PS1 settings - how to get the current folder back as the terminal title

Tags: git, bash

I recently added these lines to my ~/.bashrc file to show the current branch if i'm in a git working folder, and it works nicely for that.  However, what i've lost is that the current folder name used to be shown in the tab for the terminal i have open, and now it isn't: it always just says 'Terminal'.  Can i get that back and still keep the git stuff?  Here's the lines in question - it's the second one that's the issue, as commenting out just the second line fixes the problem.

```
source /etc/bash_completion.d/git
PS1='\h:\w$(__git_ps1 "\[\e[32m\][%s]\[\e[0m\]")$ '
```

I've been looking at explanations of the options for PS1 but can't see anything about the terminal window's title in there.  Can anyone advise?  thanks, max

EDIT

I actually manipulate PS1 already in order to have a terminal with the format

`<rvm version and gemset> <computer name> <current folder> <git branch>`

, with each part in a different color, but i've never actually seen the docs before, so thanks for the link to that.  My current PS1 setting is

```
\[\033[0;31m\]$(__my_rvm_ruby_version)\[\033[0;33m\]\h\[\033[0;37m\]:\[\033[1;33m\]\W\[\033[1;32m\]$(__git_branch)\[\033[1;32m\]$(__git_dirty) \[\033[0;37m\]$
```

Presumably i can do something like

```
export "<something> $PS1"
```

to set my terminal tab name without losing my existing settings.  I've been poking around with this though and not managed to do it.

EDIT - figured this out with the help of some of the answers below - thanks all!  I wrapped it up in a shell script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#renames the current terminal tab via the PS1 env var
source ~/.bashrc
export PS1="$PS1""\[\e]0;$1 \a\]"
```

it's called "renametab" so i can now call it with eg

```
source renametab mytabname
```

"source" is needed to export the changes into the current shell:  if i just do `renametab mytabname` the export just goes into a subshell which is killed when the script finishes.

Thanks again all, for the help!

Comment: I personally just run `update_terminal_cwd` in my `PROMPT_COMMAND`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what I have as default on my Ubuntu concerning the terminal's title:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]'
```

Prepend your PS1 with this one and it should be fine

Comment: This is what i did, to avoid losing my current PS1 settings:  `foo` should be replaced by the actual value.  `export PS1="$PS1"'\[\e]0;foo \a\]'`

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
PS1="$PS1"'\h:\w$(__git_ps1 "\[\e[32m\][%s]\[\e[0m\]")$ '
```

But it would help to know what PS1 is being set to earlier in `~/.bashrc` or in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: This works beautifully - I love the reference to the existing variable!  With my .bashrc, I had to drop the `\h:\w` to remove redundant entries: `PS1="$PS1"'$(__git_ps1 "\[\e[32m\][%s]\[\e[0m\]")$ '`

Answer (score 2):

If you're lucky, your terminal is Xterm compatible, and you can use the ANSI sequences to set your terminal title.

Instead of giving you the sequence, I'll point you to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Control-Sequences.html). Now, you can colorize your prompt. The sequence you need is described as *xterm title hack* which is what it is.

You can also use the control sequences in the prompt to help set `PS1`. These can be found in the BASH manpage under [PROMPTING](http://man.cx/bash#heading27).

And here's what I have in my `.bashrc`:

```
PS1="\e]0;BASH: \u@\h\aBASH \v: \u@\h:\w\n\$ "
```

- `\e]0;BASH: \u@\h\a` - Set Window title

  - `\e]` - Send ESC character followed by closed left bracket. This is the start of an ANSI command sequence.
  - `0;` - Zero followed by a semicolon. The following string sets the title
  - `BASH: \u@\h\` - My Window Title

    - `\u` - User Name
    - `@` - The @ sign
    - `\h` - Host Name
  - `\a` - The BEL (Cnrl-G) which ends my title
- `BASH \v: \u@\h:\w\n\$` - Sets my prompt

  - `BASH \v:` - The string *BASH* followed by the version. My default shell is Ksh, so when I am using the BASH shell, I want to see the word *BASH* in my prompt
  - `\u` - The user name
  - `\h` - The Host name
  - `\w` - The current working directory (HOME based)
  - `\n` - New line - My prompt is two lines. This way, long directories don't take up command line  space.
  - `\$` - Dollar sign or `#` if you have root privileges.

Play around and have fun. Try the different escape sequences. Add color. Embed the GIT stuff. Explore.

Remember, it's just a computer. The worst you can do is cause the whole system to come crashing down and delete all of your valuable work, lose your job, and become a hopeless pariah whose only means of income will be asking customers if they want fries with that. Unless, you work at a bank. Then you also can bring down the entire global economy.

Comment: I didn't realise i could wreck my life so thoroughly via the PS1 var!  ;-)  Thanks for the link to the docs, and for not saying `rtfm noob lol`.  Please see the edit in my OP - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the truelly helpless (like myself). Here is my Bash RC that includes git branch name in the prompt and sets the window title. Notice this uses the PROMPT_COMMAND for __git_ps1, which sets PS1 internally. When using __git_ps1 this way it takes 2 arguments. The first argument is the string before the branch name, the second argument is the string after the branch name.

```
#
# ~/.bashrc
#

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return

source ~/git/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh

alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias cd..='cd ..'

c_reset='\[\e[0m\]'
c_prompt='\[\e[1;31m\]'
c_path='\[\e[0;33m\]'

if [ -f ~/git/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh ]; then
. ~/git/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh
GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=true
GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=true
GIT_PS1_UNTRACKEDFILES=true
# Below, The section "\[\e]0;\w\a\]" sets the window title
PROMPT_COMMAND="__git_ps1 '${c_path}\w${c_reset}' '\n\u@\t${c_prompt}-->${c_reset}\[\e]0;\w\a\]' "
fi

#PS1 is set by the __git_ps1 script above, so comment out below
#PS1='\w\n[\u@\t]$>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use PROMPT_COMMAND and let PS1 just be the prompt.  For example:

PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#$HOME/~}"; echo -ne "\007"'

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD/$HOME/~} - ${USER}@${HOSTNAME}\007"'
```

which results in a window title like this:

```
/home/tkirk - tkirk@hostname
```